# How do I configure my gnome pannel if it does not respond to right-click?

Tags: gnome3

[image]

> $ gnome-session --version
>   gnome-session 3.6.2
>
> $ cat /etc/*-release
>   Fedora release 18 (Spherical Cow)

I want to customize my gnome-pannel - the bar at the top of the screen. However, right-clicking on an empty area of the bar produces no result (my mouse works fine, mkay). How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install some obscure extensions to modify this panel. Look at https://extensions.gnome.org/ to get whatever suits your needs.
Expect all extensions to break after the next Gnome upgrade though.
J.

Comment: Extensions? Unity instead of Gnome? What's wrong with these people :(

Answer (score 1):

In gnome3 there's no more easy configuration for panels (as in gnome2). There's a lot of change - you should read some comparison lists.